# MySql command to update info in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I'm working on a personal project where i want to get information of a customer from my database. However, i keep failing. The sql command i have:

```
 "SELECT * FROM `customer` WHERE `ID` =@_ID AND `Naam` LIKE '" + tbKlantZoeken.Text + "'AND `E-mail` =@_EMAIL AND `Telefoon` =@_TEL"
```

The database connection is working, and another code related to the database is working aswell. So i guess it is my sql code? If not, Here's my code where i use it:

```
//Get info

        db_connection();
        MySqlCommand cmdZoeken = new MySqlCommand();
        cmdZoeken.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `customer` WHERE `ID` =@_ID AND `Naam` LIKE '" + tbKlantZoeken.Text + "'AND `E-mail` =@_EMAIL AND `Telefoon` =@_TEL";
        cmdZoeken.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_ID", _ID);
        cmdZoeken.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_EMAIL", _EMAIL);
        cmdZoeken.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TEL", _TEL);
        cmdZoeken.Connection = connect;
        MySqlDataReader tbZoeken = cmdZoeken.ExecuteReader();
        if (tbZoeken.Read())
        {
            connect.Close();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Other part:

```
//use code

        db_connection();
        string _ID = "ID";
        string _EMAIL = "EMAIL";
        string _TEL = "TEL";
        try
        {
            bool Z = Klant_zoeken(_ID, _EMAIL, _TEL);
            if (Z)
            {
                tbKResultaat.Text = _ID + " " + " " + _EMAIL + " " + _TEL;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
```

At this part, when it fails, the "throw" doesn't work aswell. It just crashes, but i think that is a question for another time...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to change `cmdZoeken.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TEL", _TEL);` to `cmdZoeken.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_TEL", _TEL);`

Comment: Why do you use parameters for everything but 'naam'? It is a sql injection joy and possible source of parsing errors. Also if you ask help about your code not working don't forget to tell us the exact error message.

Comment: @Steve The error i'm getting is not relevant. The problem is i cant get the information i want to get. I changed Tel to _Tel, and stopped getting an error, but still no information

Comment: @Alex Thanks! It stopped it from crashing, so it works i guess? But the main problem remains: It still doesn't show any information

Comment: And what information do you expect to see? You don't use the Reader for anything but just to check if the row exists or not.

Comment: @Steve Well, i was tring to do:

    tbKResultaat.Text = cmdZoeken.GetString(0);

But that doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: I am sorry but I have lost you. Your comment doesn't match anything in the code above. Probably you are not posting some important part of your code or it is just me.

Answer (score 1):

Check with this:- You have missing space between some words. Also add % mark for like according to your requirement. Unless use as Naam` = tbKlantZoeken.Text without like

```
 "SELECT * FROM `customer` WHERE `ID` =@_ID AND `Naam` LIKE '" +  
 tbKlantZoeken.Text + "' AND `E-mail` =@_EMAIL AND `Telefoon` =@_TEL";
```

Comment: That solved the Error of not connecting, but still no information in the textbox.

Comment: pls check you sql query.  As I said pls use Like proper way

Answer (score 0):

Try this
/Get info

```
    db_connection();
    MySqlCommand cmdZoeken = new MySqlCommand();
    cmdZoeken.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE ID =@_ID AND Naam LIKE '" + tbKlantZoeken.Text + "%'AND E-mail =@_EMAIL AND Telefoon =@_TEL";
    cmdZoeken.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_ID", _ID);
    cmdZoeken.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_EMAIL", _EMAIL);
    cmdZoeken.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TEL", _TEL);
    cmdZoeken.Connection = connect;
    MySqlDataReader tbZoeken = cmdZoeken.ExecuteReader();
    if (tbZoeken.Read())
    {
        connect.Close();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove single quates from Table_name and Column_name-

try select statement like this-

```
  cmdZoeken.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE ID =@_ID AND Naam LIKE '%" + tbKlantZoeken.Text + "%'AND E-mail =@_EMAIL AND Telefoon =@_TEL";
```

Comment: When i do as you say, it gives me this error: Unknown column 'E' in 'where clause'. I guess that is the "E" from E-mail?

Comment: use    [E-mail]     in place of     E-mail.

Comment: This is the correct syntax. Please use this

cmdZoeken.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE ID =@_ID AND Naam LIKE '%'+" + tbKlantZoeken.Text + "+'%' AND [E-mail] =@_EMAIL AND Telefoon =@_TEL";